What's the name of the RTS subgenre played in a connected graph where nodes produce troops that you can send to adjacent nodes?
There is a type of RTS game that I remember playing in the late 00's that consisted of a partially connected graph with nodes producing troops constantly and the player having to choose when to send half the troops from one node to an adjacent one, either to reinforce it or to attack it.
It looks somewhat like this:

What's the term I can use to search for this genre?

Is it actually an RTS (Real-Time Strategy) game, or turn-based? The type of gameplay you're describing sounds closer to the latter. And can you tell us about the larger goals those games tend to have (or your specific example had)?

Node-based Strategy Game
It's not a well used genre, but seems to be a way to describe. You can additionally add Real-Time or Turn-Based (although searching Node Based Turn Based is going to be awful in most search engines) depending on how the game plays.
https://www.reddit.com/r/RealTimeStrategy/comments/d31psm/nodebased_rts_concept/
Has a few examples in there like Solarmax 2 and Galcon 2.
Turn based ones would be like Risk.

I actually found that Reddit thread as well looking for an answer to this question, but the game described is a concept in development by (what I assume is) a single indie developer, so not much of a standard description. Moreover, the problem with "node-based" is that it doesn't say anything about the gameplay, and only about a visual characteristic. If you look up Solarmax 2 or galcon 2, it's hard to even find the word "node" to begin with.

I agree with Joaquim that the term is broad, but it did return examples of what I was looking for as the first few results on Google. Both Solarmax 2 and Galcon 2 fit the criteria, but indeed don't use the term. Perhaps it's a non-named mechanic instead of a genre.

Oh for sure it's not like a term you can see in Steam or anything. It's something that could be used in future though if people tag games like it with it. Either that or needs a specific game and can call it an "X-like" like "Souls-like". But I struggle to think of like a famous one for it. "Risk like" doesn't bring up anything.

I'd say games like this fit into the "4X game" definition: (EXplore, EXpand, EXploit, EXterminate).
4X differs from real-time strategy (RTS) games: both are subgenres of strategy games but play quite different. 4X games focus more on civilisation building (diplomacy, economy, map control), where RTS games focus more on unit control/combat strategy/micro. 4X games can have more complex relations between players. RTSs tend to only distinguish players as ally or enemy, where 4X games may allow for greater diplomatic play (trading supplies, performing favours etc) or have win conditions not tied to combat (maintain peace for X amount of turns, etc)
Probably the closest game I can think to your description is Neptune's Pride, a game that has nodes (star systems/planets) that produce ships and research. Ships can be sent to capture more nodes, and nodes can be upgraded to produce faster, or research upgrades faster. Combat is (mostly) a numbers game: if you have 12 ships hit a node with 10 enemy ships defending it, you will capture the node with 2 ships remaining. Upgrades/research levels may factor into this calculation as well.

The visuals and broad concept of Neptune's Pride fit what I'm looking for, but 4X implies a grander purpose than the genre I'm looking for. I would guess they could be made as a 4X game, but the ones I remember are almost puzzle-like, where the disposition of the nodes in the stage dictates the difficulty and strategy needed. Gameplay-wise, they are mostly a matter of timing the troop incursions to conquer another node while avoiding leaving a node vulnerable. I will complement the question with these details, now I realize they are relevant.

@RodrigoBorges I get what you mean. 4X is definitely a broader genre. Glad HSharp was able to offer a more specific alternative :)
